# Return XML document with REST API

Tags: c#, xml, rest

I would like to return a xml document from rest api request:

```
[HttpPost]
public string getClassXml(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
     var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
     ClassXML classid = new ClassXML();
     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

     try
     {
         var data = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
         classid = serializer.Deserialize<ClassXML>(data.ToString().Trim());
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     { 
         throw new Exception(ex.Message);
     }

     string path = ASDb.ReadValue("SELECT definitionxml FROM alclass WHERE classid='" + classid.classID + "'").ToString();

     XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Resource\\" + percorso);
     reader.Read();
     doc.Load(reader);

     return doc.innerXml;
}
```

But in this way I get a string, I would like to have a XmlDocument not a string. I tried also to return the XmlDocument doc, but it gives me an error: he 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'. 
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you make XmlDocument from the xml you get from method on consuming end.

Comment: Returning a complex class like XmlDocument is not recommended when creating a web service; if someone accesses your service from another language (like PHP) then they will not be able to use the complex class.  Better to leave it as it is so that the API is open to other languages.  If you don't want it to be open, then why are you bothering with using REST?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As someone wrote here just a few seconds ago (but then deleted his answer) the problem is that XmlDocument is not serializable, if you use XmlElement instead is ok. Here is what I did:

```
[HttpPost]
public XmlElement getClassXml(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    ClassXML classid = new ClassXML();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    try
    {
        var data = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        classid = serializer.Deserialize<ClassXML>(data.ToString().Trim());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }

    string path = ASDb.ReadValue("SELECT definitionxml FROM alclass WHERE classid='" + classid.classID + "'").ToString();

     XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Resource\\" + percorso);
     reader.Read();
     doc.Load(reader);
     XmlElement element = doc.DocumentElement;

     return element;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the issue isn't with your API layer, but when you're trying to use your XmlTextReader?

`XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Resource\\" + percorso);`

What does your XML that you're trying to read in look like? Have you checked that it's well formed?

In terms of "returning XML document with REST API", I would suggest that you just output the XML document as a string with the appropriate MIME type, doing something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage getClassXml(HttpRequestMessage req)
{

     ...

     XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Resource\\" + percorso);
     reader.Read();
     doc.Load(reader);

     HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent(doc.innerXml, Encoding.UTF8,"application/xml") };
     return response;
}
```

REST API outputs should map to standard internet mime types (eg JSON data, images, text, etc - not XmlDocument). Whatever is consuming your REST API can just take the text and turn it into a XmlDocument if necessary.

As an aside, you don't seem to even use half the code in the example you provided and you can probably clean it up:

```
string path = ASDb.ReadValue("SELECT definitionxml FROM alclass WHERE classid='" + classid.classID + "'").ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but if I now want to change from HttpPost to HttpGet how would I get the parameters in the following url: `http://localhost/arcosat/api/ws/GetClassXml?classid=myclass`
I want to get the "myclass" string but with `req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` it doesn't work anymore